# Datatables columnfilter date-range not working (undefined~undefined) value on date

Tags: c#, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm having problem with jQuery DataTables date range filtering. I'm getting (`sSearch_0` = `undefined~undefined`) value with Bootstrap Datepicker. When I put a `null` value on first column instead of `type: "date-range"`, the 3rd column filter is working fine.

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Implements the dataTables plugin on the HTML table
    var oTable = $('#transactionHistoryDataTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "api/Sitecore/Account/DataProviderAction",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aoColumns": [
           { "sName": "Date", "bSortable": false },
           { "sName": "Name", "bSortable": false },
           { "sName": "Bracket", "bSortable": false },
           { "sName": "Activity", "bSortable": false },
        ],
        "sDom": '<"top">tip',
        "oLanguage": {
           "sEmptyTable": "Your custom message for empty table"
        }

    }).columnFilter({
        "aoColumns": [
           { type: "date-range" },
           null,
           { type: "select"},
           null,
        ]
    });



});

})(jQuery);
```

**UPDATE**

I changed my code into server side filtering like this

```
"fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
    aoData.push({ "name": "activityParam", "value": $('#activityList').val() });
    aoData.push({ "name": "dateFrom", "value": $('#dateFrom').val() });
    aoData.push({ "name": "dateTo", "value": $('#dateTo').val() });
}
```

The workaround that I've come up with works with jquery ui the problem is I can't use Jquery UI is there any other workaround?

Comment: According to the [jQuery DataTable Column Filter - Date Range filters](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dateRange.html), filter uses jQueryUI Datepicker internally. Your code doesn't show how you initialize Bootstrap Datepicker.

Comment: thats the problem i can't use jquery ui. i have change my filtering to server side like this

`                "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                    aoData.push({ "name": "activityParam", "value": $('#activityList').val() });
                    aoData.push({ "name": "dateFrom", "value": $('#dateFrom').val() });
                    aoData.push({ "name": "dateTo", "value": $('#dateTo').val() });
                }`

the problem is still on the datepicker it still needs jquery ui.. is there a way around?